# PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function pdo_query()

Tags: php

No answers were found at google and stackoverflow
The code is as follows

```
<?php
pdo_query("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ims_cyl_vip_video` (
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
`uniacid` int(5) NOT NULL,
`title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`uid` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
`openid` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`time` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
`video_url` text NOT NULL,
`share` int(3) NOT NULL,
`yvideo_url` text NOT NULL,
`type` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
`index` int(2) NOT NULL,
`video_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ims_cyl_vip_video_member` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uniacid` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `openid` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `uid` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `nickname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `avatar` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  `end_time` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `is_pay` int(2) NOT NULL,
```

Comment: "*..No answers were found at google and stackoverflow*". Ok. Then, From Where Did You Get `pdo_query()` ?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php

Comment: Do not know where to get pdo_query ()

Comment: @NanaPartykar I Would've Upvoted Your Comment, But I Couldn't Read It Through The Title Case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to create a table with PHP. Here is the simple code example from which you can create the tables: Replace the sample query with your SQL query.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

// sql to create table
$sql = "CREATE TABLE MyGuests (
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(50),
reg_date TIMESTAMP
)";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Table MyGuests created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error creating table: " . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: I actually do not know how specific code, with someone else CMS open install.php that error. The PHP version is 5.6.1

Comment: OP is clearly asking about PDO. Why would you provide an answer using mysqli?

Comment: @Chris OP is confused about PDO and pasted the raw code also he has a little knowledge of PHP. I gave him a simple solution which he accepted.

Comment: @ShahrozeNawaz, if you're going to do that you should be explicit about it. As you said, OP seems to have little knowledge of PHP. They may not even realize you changed the library being used. Unless there is a good reason to change the library (e.g. if OP was using the deprecated `mysql_` functions) please try to answer questions using the technology in the question.